# Is it If x / 100 = Int(x / 100) Then ActiveWorkbook.Save OR if x/100 = Int(x) Then ActiveWorkbook.save?

Tags: vba, excel

... to save your workbook every 100th iteration?

Its just a programming language question.

Is it If x / 100 = Int(x / 100) Then ActiveWorkbook.Save or if x/100 = Int(x) Then ActiveWorkbook.save to save your workbook every 100th itteration?

The structure of the code is like this:

`Sub queryname
for x = 1 to 20000 
'lots more code to do something/executute processes 
'more code ....
If x / 100 = Int(x) Then ActiveWorkbook.Save
End With
Next x
End Sub`

***Question is,*** Is it **if x / 100 = Int(x) Then ActiveWorkbook.Save** or should it be written as **if x/100 = Int(x/100)** **then ActiceWorkbook.Save** to do that?

= Int (x/100) makes more sense to me, (as thats how excel would see it) as your asking it if the calculation is an integer, but VBA might read it differently and put variables in a different manner, thus making = Int(x) correct in this statement context.

I think if x/100 =int(x/100) would be correct? but something else is saying to me , "no thats the way vba is designed. it doesnt read the variables that way," (kind of thing.) Any help with this question?

You can tell my knowledge of VBA syntax (if this is a syntax question) is poor.

**Aha ! stop press, I think =Int(x) would be correct as it reads it as a function of x, f(x), as in/with mathematics, and not as a variable or part of a programming loop.

You can tell im bored, but any suggestions/help with this question would be much appreciated!

Comment: `If x / 100 = Int(x / 100) Then ActiveWorkbook.Save` would work, but `If x Mod 100 = 0 Then ...` would be the preferred way of expressing it.

Comment: Doesn't Excel have an auto-save setting? I'm pretty sure it always recovers documents.

Comment: Thanks Guys . Appreciate the feedback & Help loads !

Answer (score 4):

```
If x Mod 100 = 0 Then ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

**Mod** divides two numbers and returns only the remainder. - [Mod Operator on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/mod-operator)

Comment: Thank you for the explenation & correct line ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

The first works fine:

```
Int(x/100) = x/100
```

I.e.:

```
x Mod 100 = 0
```

However the second:

```
Int(x/100) = Int(x)
```

would only work for `x = 0`, otherwise LHS is always 100 times smaller than RHS.

As a side note: `Int(x/100)` is not *"asking"* if its an integer, its *turning it into* an integer. (`Int(1.4) = 1`)

Comment: Thank you !! That is exactly what I needed/wanted to know !! Thank you very very much !!

Comment: Thank you Nick A, It was really helpful , I really appreciate it.